# How to get result from stored procedure and save result in a class attributes

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have following code:

```
public static void executeStoredProcedure(SqlCommand sp)
{
           SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
           conn.ConnectionString=Connection.getConnection();
           conn.Open();
           sp.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           sp.Connection = conn;
           sp.ExecuteNonQuery();
           conn.Close();
}
```

This code executes the stored procedure.

But my stored procedure is

```
Create procedure [dbo].[selectAllItems]
(@ItemCode varchar(50) )
as
begin
    select * from Item where ItemCode  = @ItemCode
end
```

It will return rows but how to get this result in above c# code

Comment: Why do you have a stored procedure called `selectAllItems` that doesn't return all items? And what exactly are you asking? How to execute the stored proc from `C#`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a `SqlDataReader` to read the result set returned by the stored procedure:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection.getConnection()))
using (SqlCommand sp = new SqlCommand("dbo.selectAllItems", conn))
{
       sp.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       sp.Parameters.Add("@ItemCode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = your-item-code-value-here;

       conn.Open();

       using (SqlDataReader rdr = sp.ExecuteReader())
       {
          while (rdr.Read())
          {
             // read the values from the data reader, e.g.
             // adapt to match your actual query! You didn't mentioned *what columns*
             // are being returned, and what data type they are
             string colValue1 = rdr.GetString(0);
             int colValue2 = rdr.GetInt(1);
          }
       }

       conn.Close();
}
```

With those values read from the `SqlDataReader`, you could e.g. create an object type and set its properties - or something like that - totally depends on what you want to do.

And of course : using an ORM like Entity Framework would *save* you from having to write a lot of this type of code - EF would handle this for you - automagically .

Answer (score 1):

you need to parse the parameter to you stored procedure like below

```
sp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCode", itemcode);
```

sample code

```
public DataTable SelectAllItems(string itemCode)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection.getConnection()))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("selectAllItems", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCode", itemCode);
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            adapter.Fill(dt);
        }

    }
    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Data reader 
Check the following example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx